# Current location spot on Google maps on iphone ios7 looks strange

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, ios7

I have two apps both using the newest version of google maps sdk 1.4.0

There's a weird issue I'm seeing on ios7 where the user's current location is surrounded by a white square (see image below)

I'm not really doing any funky things with the map, just that pin image over the map. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: This is a bug with the SDK for iOS7. I have reopened https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5113

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue on **Simalutor**. Both iOS 7 and 8.

Works fine on real devices.

You can check the issue in google maps api bug tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5472).